# Minify all JS files in nested folder structure of Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015, minify, visual-studio-extensions

I am looking for a solution to minify all the JS files (in a deep nested folder structure) in one go by either using visual studio extension or may be through command line.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should use glob patterns, suppose you have

outter-folder/inner-folder/inner-inner-folder

than, in the src of the minifyer you should type:

outter-folder/**/*.js and all the outter-folder's subfolders and sub-subfolder's js files are going to be minified

Comment: "src of the minifyer", which tool are you talking about here? Can you please share a link?

Comment: you can use Gulp or Grunt http://codehangar.io/concatenate-and-minify-javascript-with-gulp/